# How to stop linux from consuming bandwidth?

Tags: fedora, modem, bandwidth

I use fedora 14, and when I start system monitor, i can see that it already downloaded 40 Mb, without doing anything. How can i stop programs that secretly consume my bandwith? I use a prepaid modem with limited bandwith (500 Mb). I guess yum is consuming some bandwith with updates checking and downloading the xmls

Answer (score 1):

Try to investigate what's happening with [nethogs](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fnethogs.sourceforge.net%2F&ei=WoOoTYbiPIWSOobjkN8J&usg=AFQjCNFbG6Xxg9HiC_yQJlmBisGsYgE7oQ&sig2=klZ27q4Oy2BUHZzrIhSgtA).

Also there are tcpdump, wireshark, iotop.

Answer (score 0):

If you determine that yum is the culprit, you may want to raise the value of `metadata_expire` in `/etc/yum.conf`. This is the TTL for the yum metadata. Raising it should cause yum to fetch less frequently.

Installing `yum-presto` will use delta RPMs for updates (this may be the default now?), which will be smaller than the standard RPMs.

You may want to run `/usr/bin/gpk-prefs` and turn down the frequency of checking for updates from daily to weekly.